# Integration of (d-1)-dimensional functions on finite element surfaces

Tags: finite-element, integration, discontinuous-galerkin, mapping-strategy

I am trying to integrate a function $\hat u$ on the common surface of discontinuous finite elements. The function $\hat u$ lives in a $d-1$-dimensional space of functions defined on the element interfaces. However, the unique mapping of the interface and functions with support on the interface to a reference element is not straightforward.

Consider the interface $\partial K$ joining elements $K^\pm$. We have functions $\hat u$ defined on $\partial K$ and $u^\pm$ defined on $K^\pm$, respectively. It is necessary to compute surface integrals along $\partial K$ from the perspectives of $K^\pm$, i.e. the surface integral is computed twice - once on both element. However, I am having trouble determining the appropriate mapping from $d$-dimensional functions $u^\pm$ to $d-1$ space. Namely, should I enforce a mapping in global coordinates or reference coordinates?

My current approach is to consider a point $x$ on $\partial K$ and to determine the two points $\hat x^\pm$ on reference elements $\hat K^\pm$ that both map to $x$. In this approach, the interface has a fixed global orientation. For example, in the case of the 2-D line interface with a 1-D reference element joining two 2-D triangular elements, the $\hat x^\pm$ mapping to $x$ differ. A consequence of this scheme is that the determinants of the Jacobian are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign on $K^\pm$. However, this scheme seems to not be correct and I'm afraid this approach may be over-complicating the problem.

In particular, I am using integration rules to evaluate integrals of the form

\begin{equation}
    \int_{\partial K} f_h^\pm \left(\hat u, u^\pm, n^\pm \right) \cdot \mu = \sum_q f \left( \hat u(x_q), u^\pm(x_q), n^\pm \right) \cdot \mu(x_q) J w_q
\end{equation}

where $\mu$ is some test function on $\partial K$, $n^\pm$ are the outward-pointing normals to $K^\pm$ and $J$ is the Jacobian of the mapping.

Is my mapping scheme correct? If not, what is the appropriate mapping scheme for, e.g., the the case where $\partial K$ is a line joining two triangles? What would $J$ be for this scheme? Some resources use the absolute value of $J$ in their description of change of variables while others do not. When the absolute value needed?

Answer (score 1):

> should I enforce a mapping in global coordinates or reference coordinates?

Yes, it is important to make sure you have a consistent mapping since when you want to compute $f^*_h(u^+, u^-)$ you need to evaluate $u^+$ and $u^-$ on both sides of the jump discontinuity at $x$.

> A consequence of this scheme is that the determinants of the Jacobian are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign

This is correct. If you think of this as a flux across the interface, material is moving from one element to the other through the interface. Naturally this means you are subtracting from one side and adding to the other.

> What would $J$ be for this scheme?

I don't know the generalization for integrating on a $d-1$ dimensional surface embedded in $d$ dimensional space (I have an idea of what it might look like, but not positive), however I do know what it should be in the special case you have a 1D curve embedded in 2D space or a 2D curve embedded in 3D space.

1D curve in 2D space:
$$
\int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot \partial_{\eta} \vec{x} d \eta
$$

2D surface in 3D space:
$$
\int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot (\partial_{\eta_0} \vec{x} \times \partial_{\eta_1} \vec{x}) d \eta_0 d \eta_1
$$

where $\vec{\eta}$ is the $d-1$ dimensional face coordinates.

It is common to break this further into a non-negative scalar times a unit normal vector, so you get
$$
\int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot \hat{n} \|\partial_{\eta} \vec{x}\|_2 d \eta\\
\int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{\partial K} \vec{f} \cdot \hat{n} \|\partial_{\eta_0} \vec{x} \times \partial_{\eta_1} \vec{x}\|_2 d \eta_0 d \eta_1
$$

If your 1D curve is a straight line segment, then you can further simplify $\|\partial_{\eta} \vec{x}\|_2$ to a constant which is the ratio of the line segment's length to the face coordinate's length. ex.: if $\eta \in [-1,1]$, then
$$
\|\partial_{\eta} \vec{x}\|_2 = \frac{L_{\partial K}}{2}
$$